# saving points in a grid, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a class, let's call it `MyClass` that has a point and information about that point and a two dimensional grid.  I want to save all the points in each grid area. Example `grid[0,0]` contains 3 points and `grid[0,1]` has 2 points, `grid[0,2]` 0 points `grid[1,0]` 4 points .....  So I want a 2 dimension array that is a list of a custom class, how can set this up?

`int [,] x = new int[3,3]` => is an array of ints

`myclass [,] = new myclass[3,3]` =>is an array of `MyClass`
but how do I declare a list of `MyClass`?

Comment: A `List<myClass>` or what do you want?? Or a `List<List<myClass>>`?

Comment: Neither,  I want a multidimensional array that contains a list of myclass, so I can say what myclasses are at [1,1}

Comment: `List<myClass>[,] gridPoints = new List<myClass>[n,m] ;` ?